# failed to import `ray` on my jupyter notebook

Tags: pytorch, ray

While working on my school's Linux server, I encountered an issue while attempting to install and import Ray in my Jupyter Notebook. I successfully installed the package ray==2.4.0, but encountered an error when trying to import it, specifically stating "no module named ray.__raylet".

However, I installed the same version of Ray on my local machine and it was installed and imported without any problems.

I'm seeking guidance on how to address this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO, are you able to install other packages or is this problem unique to the `ray` package? Have you tried restarting your kernel maybe?